# BGE Facing Plane

Tags: game-engine

I'm creating a game in Blender. The enemies in the FPS are sprites on a flat plane. The only problem I have is making the flat plane to where it's constantly facing the player camera similar to Doom, because the enemies aren't in 3D. Is there a way to make the flat plane mesh constantly face the player camera using the Logic, or is there any Python coding involved?

Answer (score 2):

If you enable `Billboard` in Materials Tab under `Game Settings > Face Orientation`, the planes local x-axis will always face the camera while the z-axis remains as it is (= the object rotates only on its z-axis).

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/game_engine/materials.html#face-orientation

[image: Game Settings Panel]

Comment: Good one red @Momel .  My version hasn't got that.  Would have been handy!

Comment: Correction - I did find it, thanks to your post. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a very good answer but it should get you there.  I've dug out the logic bricks of a game I made a long time ago when learning the BGE.  The pic pretty much says it all...

[image]

To bring the enemy sprites' logic up, select them in the 3D window.

The "Near" sensor detects when the player gets within the distance range you type in and sets off 3 actuators.  The one you're looking for is "Steering".  That will make the enemy face the player or whatever you nominate.  I see I'd set him to an almost zero velocity. (coward that I am)

The other two are broadcasting messages which other "Sensors" can pick up and act upon or ignore.

I imagine you'd need your enemy sprites to pick up a broadcast "message" and "Steer" them towards the camera or player.  Same with anything else that has to do the same.

Good luck with your game.  It was a lot of fun as I recall.